# Report builder getting percentage of row total divided by subtotal

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I need to get the percentage of a row value divided by the total for each group.

#### Report screen shot

[image: Report screen shot]

So the far right column I want to be the units sold column divided by the total so 10046/35181

I am using Report builder 3.0

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write an expression that sums the Units Sold for the group represented by the "Total" cell and incorporate that into the calculation.

For example:

```
=Fields!UnitsSold.Value/Sum(Fields!UnitsSold.Value, "GroupName")
```

where "GroupName" is the name of the grouping that is above Style (Type?).